# Best way to Import more than 7.000 contacts to CoreData

Tags: objective-c, core-data

i try to importer more than 7.000 contacts to CoreData through, 
now i try to using a thread but the app crash

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 

NSLog(@"threadSendToBackground");
for (NSDictionary *contactDetail in [[xmlDictionary valueForKey:@"response"] valueForKey:@"entry"]) {

    Contacts *AddCDContacts = (Contacts *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];

    [AddCDContacts setDisplayName:[contactDetail valueForKey:@"displayName"]];

    NSError *error;
    if (appDelegate.managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([appDelegate.managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Handle the error.
            NSLog(@"Error saving");
        } 
    }        
}

[pool release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the Core Data article ([Efficiently Importing Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html)) that deals with this? It will provide you with plenty of tips that you may find useful in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Don't save the context in the for loop, just save it once at the end.
Also, especially on devices with limited memory, try to reuse objects instead of assigning new constantly.

Comment: No problem! Have you tried removing the multiple save? I'm pretty sure that's what's causing the crash of your app.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use a managed object context on more than one thread. If you're using Core Data in a background thread, you must create a separate `NSManagedObjectContext` for that thread.

Definitely read the [Core Data and Concurrency](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) chapter in the Core Data Programming Guide, you will shoot yourself in the foot otherwise.